# Elasticsearch: Fetch document _id by source id

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I've recently started using ElasticSearch and I am not able to get document **_id(E2EZ4nYBaAtUNwzCDsL9)** using source **id(26.0)**.

Example:

**Query**:

```
GET /_search?index=xyz
{
  "_source": ["firstName", "lastName", "id", "email"]
}
```

Below is my elastic search query result:

```
{
  "took" : 431,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 98,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "xyz",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "E2EZ4nYBaAtUNwzCDsL9",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "lastName" : "mehta",
          "firstName" : "zenny",
          "id" : 26.0,
          "email" : "zmehta@gmail.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Below I have attached code to fetch **_id** from the source **id** field.

```
SearchSourceBuilder sourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

    QueryBuilder matchSpecificFieldQuery = QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery(id, "id");
    sourceBuilder.query(matchSpecificFieldQuery);
    sourceBuilder.from(0);
    sourceBuilder.size(5);
    sourceBuilder.timeout(new TimeValue(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)); // how long the search is allowed to take

    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();

    String[] includes = new String[] { "id" };

    String[] excludes = Strings.EMPTY_ARRAY;
    sourceBuilder.fetchSource(includes, excludes);
    searchRequest.indices(INDEX_TYPE);
    searchRequest.source(sourceBuilder);

    SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

    String docId = searchResponse.getHits().getHits()[0].getId();

    DeleteRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteRequest(INDEX_TYPE, docId);
```

But nothing seems to work.

Currently, I have only the id field value, But for the delete request, I need to fetch _id using source id. How do I delete a record by _id in ElasticSearch?

Comment: `searchResponse.getHits().getHits()[0].getId()` shoult be the ES native ID, not your custom ID. For your custom ID you should do: `searchResponse.getHits().getHits()[0].getSourceAsMap().get("id")`.

Answer (score 0):

You should call client by **deleteRequest** like this.

```
DeleteRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteRequest(INDEX_TYPE, docId);

DeleteResponse deleteResponse = client.delete(deleteRequest,questOptions.DEFAULT);

if (deleteResponse.getResult() == DocWriteResponse.Result.NOT_FOUND) {
   // Do something if the document to be deleted was not found
 }
```